# managing different rails 2.3.x versions in development/production with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, version-numbering

I'm trying to configure Bundler to work with different Rails 2.3.x versions using the [guide in the bunder website](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html), so I could test a version in dev environment before its used in production. I have the following Gemfile:

```
# some common gems

group :development do
  # installed on dev machine
  gem "rails", "2.3.11" 

  #... some more dev gems
end

group :production do
  gem "rails", "2.3.8", :path => 'vendor/rails'
end
```

When I try to run the server in dev mode, I get a bundler error `You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. You specified: rails (= 2.3.11) and rails (= 2.3.8) (Bundler::DslError)`. What am I missing? I thought the goal of Bundler was to help me do just that. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://gembundler.com/groups.html

I think you just need to specify which group you're installing. I think by default it just goes through all the groups, so just specify what you don't need.

```
bundle install --without production
```

from the same page:

Require the gems in particular groups, noting that gems outside of a named group are in the :default group

```
Bundler.require(:default, :development)
```

Require the default gems, plus the gems in a group named the same as the current Rails environment

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

In this case, you need the second one.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, although I'm not trying to install gems, just run script/server - gems are either installed on the machine or available in vendor/gems. I get that error when rails is trying to initialize.

Comment: then you just have to require certain gems depending on your environment. if you read that page, check out my edited answer

Comment: the Bundler.require(..) solution doesn't seem to work for different gem sources like I have it set up (still get that error). I looked into it, and it seems to be planned for Bundler 1.1 (at least according to this http://bit.ly/bjdk0C). Thanks again!